# Certain components show fail to show up on screen and inspect element isn't helping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I'm trying to design a UI that looks like this

[image]

So far what I have is this

[image]

The problem I'm having is getting the info icon to show up where it's supposed to be and getting  the direct text and create icon on the top left corner. I also can't have the primary and general show up in my UI like Instagrams and the scrollbar on my drawer goes all the way up instead of stopping where the appbar is.

Here's my code

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import Badge from "@material-ui/core/Badge";
import InfoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Info";
import ListItemAvatar from "@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {};
}
const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  appBar: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));
const SmallAvatar = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 11,
    height: 11,
    color: "green",
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
}))(Avatar);
const Messaging = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dummy = "Active now";
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position='fixed' className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <Avatar>
            <PersonIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography variant='h6'>adib.akm</Typography>
          <InfoIcon />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant='permanent'
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
        anchor='left'>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Divider />
        <List>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Badge
                overlap='circle'
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                badgeContent={<SmallAvatar />}>
                <Avatar>
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </Badge>
            </ListItemAvatar>

            <ListItemText primary='Photos' secondary={dummy} />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Badge
                overlap='circle'
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                badgeContent={<SmallAvatar />}>
                <Avatar>
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </Badge>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText primary='Work' secondary={dummy} />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Badge
                overlap='circle'
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                badgeContent={<SmallAvatar />}>
                <Avatar>
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </Badge>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText primary='Vacation' secondary={dummy} />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Messaging);
```

This is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-monad-dsvf8?file=/src/index.js

Comment: you should also include a demo link, since this is react code, codesandbox.io is good way to share

Comment: Added demo link